# jQuery/JavaScript Active link in my script - bad underline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Today i have the following problem. I would like to prepreing script which will be emphasized on active link which I clidked. I don't know how to do. Could you give me some advice??

I have idea, but i don't know if it is good solution.

I think that I should prepare css class. It should look like this:

```
.active {
text_decoration: underline;
}
```

I think that I will use method .addClass("active") and removeClass("active")

I prepared simple code, but it doesn't work proprely.

```
$(function(){

    $("li input").on( "click", function(e) 
    {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Nowadays i don't know how to remove underline with previous element(object)

```
<ul>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(0)" value="MADRID" name="MADRID"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(0)" value="AMSTERDAM" name="AMSTERDAM"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(4)" value="ABU DHABI" name="ABU DHABI"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(1)" value="LONDON" name="LONDON"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(8)" value="HONG KONG" name="HONG KONG"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(8)" value="CHINA" name="CHINA"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(3)" value="ATHENS" name="ATHENE"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(8)" value="SINGAPORE" name="SINGAPORE"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(4)" value="MOSCOW" name="MOSCOW"/></li>
                    <li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(7)" value="JAKARTA" name="JAKARTA"/></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some bugs

```
$(function(){
    var ins = $("li input").on( "click", function(e) {
        ins.not(this).removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

and

```
.active {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aJJC5/)

Comment: ok, it works, i have another question i would like to underline one element when i refresh page.

Comment: @DawidPierwoła just add the class active to the desired element

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make only one button active when it is clicked.

```
$(function(){

    $("li input").on( "click", function(e) 
    {
       $(this).addClass("active").siblings().parent().find('input').removeClass("active");

    });
});
```

And also you have a typo in your css code snippet.
It should be :

```
.active{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

If you want some element remain active upon a page refresh then you can simply add the "active" class on html markup as :

```
<li><input type="button" onClick="Clock(0)" value="MADRID" name="MADRID" class="active" /></li>
```

on whatever list item's input you want

Answer (score 0):

Change you Class Declaration in CSS as

```
.active
{
    text-decoration : underline; /* YOU HAD WRITTEN 'text_decoration' */
}
```

replace '_' to '-'