# make active while click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have some content which I have displayed by id when click. I need a javascript function for active links (class name is `.active`), and it will remove(`.active`) when other links have been active,

An example of the code structure is:

```
<ul class="product">
    <li><a href="#myanmar" class="active">Myanmar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#madagascar">Madagascar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#usa">United States of America</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ethiopia">Ethiopia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#brazil">Brazil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#australia">Australia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#china">China</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kenya">Kenya</a></li>
    <li><a href="#canada">Canada</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: where is your jQuery / Javascript ?

Comment: Refer to these
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597135/jquery-how-to-highlight-a-menu-link-when-clicked
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637262/jquery-javascript-active-link-in-my-script-bad-underline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but to add to Davids answer this is what you are going to want to do:
first check if the link you are clicking has the class of active before you do anything so you can avoid flicker (I am assuming you are going to jump to divs either animated or not)

```
 $('ul.product a').click(function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
                 $(".active").removeClass("active");
                 $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
            return false;//this prevents flicker
       }
 });
```

Comment: +1 for this, more robust and better suited for big link lists

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('ul.product a').click(function(){
    $('ul.product a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8nky/

Comment: i would use $(".active").removeClass("active"). your solution is fine for a couple of links but a big list would start to get slow, and obviously its better to teach the right way to do things

Comment: In this instance my solution will address the op's problem, you have a valid point though, maybe add as an answer?

Comment: no I definitely agree that it works, but my argument to you is that (I know you know what your doing) but for people learning we might as well show them the correct path, as I would have liked that same courtesy when I learned.. It was not meant to offend.

Comment: Hey no offence taken :) that's why I love SO, I learn something here everyday!

Answer (score 0):

```
check : http://jsfiddle.net/en2LT/
```

try this...when clicking the link you should addclass active and removeclass active